# What is the difference between the ‘omnifunc’ and ‘completefunc’ autocomplete in Vim, except for the invocation key mapping?

Tags: vim

Is there any difference in functionality between these two types of complete-functions in Vimscript?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Technically, there is no difference in implementation of both
User-defined completion (see `:help compl-function`, `:help 'completefunc'`) and Omni completion (see `:help compl-omni`, `:help 'omnifunc'`). Both of them work by calling a function of special
semantics that locates the start of the expression to be completed at
the current position, and provides appropriate completion suggestions
(see `:help complete-functions`).

Where the difference between these two types of completion manifests
itself, is the purpose of completion. User-defined completion should
be customized by the user themselves according to conditions specific
to a particular completion idea. Omni completion is supposed to be
filetype-specific. Hence, separate Omni completion functions for
different filetypes are loaded automatically by Vim from
`autoload/‹ft›complete.vim` files, where `‹ft›` stands for a
particular filetype. See those Omni completion files for C or Python
filetypes as a reference.